# Putty Codes for servers

Tags: web-services, ssh, putty

This is first time I'm working with Putty.very interesting
I want, how to install apache,php for new web-server via Putty.
rpm -qa | grep apache
rpm -qa | grep php
Those codes are how to find apache,php version for old web-server
i have some idea about those codes, But i don't know meaning of those codes

```
tar vxzf libssh2-1.4.2.tar.gz      
cd libssh2-1.4.2        
./configure      
make     
make install
```

Is this correct way to install apache,php for new web-server via Putty?

Comment: Uh, so you expect totally random strangers on the web to know the login details of YOUR server? It's a shame we can only downvote by 1 point...

Comment: No. I want to install php and apache via putty.
Yast better for installation ?
any good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the production servers installations YaST2 is better than putty.
because putty we have to includes codes and paths ,YaST2 is like normal windows software installation process.
We have to set path YaST2 then it works correctly.